# How to ignore a part of a code within for loop after first iteration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a question which seems to be simple. I have a for loop where I call different functions at each iteration. Some of these functions are only needed to be used at the first iteration if a certain condition holds. One way to solve this problem is checking the condition with "if" statement before calling the related function, but I am wondering if there is any other way to take care of this since I have more than 10 functions with the same situation (with different condition of course)? As an example, please take a look at the following pseudo code:

```
for Iteration < Generation
    ...
    if ('certain condition 01 holds true')
        output = function01(arguments)
    end
    ...
    ...
    if ('certain condition 02 holds true')
        output = function02(arguments)
    end
    ...    
    ...
    if ('certain condition 10 holds true')
        output = function10(arguments)
    end
    ...
 end
```

If I have, lets say, 10000 iterations, each of these "if" statement should be evaluated 10000 times which increase the computation time significantly. Is it possible to use object-oriented programming and classes instead of functions to make it better and probably faster?

Comment: Your question is somewhat self-answering. If you have to check some conditions in every iteration so you can conclude whether to do run some function, you can't avoid evaluating them. In this case, my bet would be that the fastest way is one using simplest language construct (`if` seems appropriate here)...

Answer (score 4):

If you always need to check some conditions then there is no way to avoid it. However, if you know that the first two conditions can only arise in the first, say, 500 loops, then split the big loop into two - the first one with all 10 conditions (500 iterations), and the second one with just 8 (total - 500 iterations).

Another important thing to remember is to use [`elseif`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/elseif.html) in your conditions or [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) in your loops (provided that the conditions are mutually exclusive - I inferred this from your code sample). In this way you make sure that once the relevant condition has been found, the rest of the `if` statements will not be executed. Additionally, you should check the most probable condition at the beginning of your loop. I.e. if you know that in most cases condition 5 is most likely, then condition 5 should be checked first. In this way you can decrease the number of times `if` statements are evaluated.

Lastly, you could use the [`switch`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement - it is more readable than multiple `elseif`'s and if one of the conditions is true, then the following ones are automatically ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about classes and object-orientation but you could change the ordering inside your function to something like this:

```
...
% 'iteration' 1
if (condition1) then
    output = function1(args)
end

if (condition2) then
    output = function2(args)
end
.
.
.
for ix = 2:max
    % code inside loop
end
```

In words, put the code which is only called on the first iteration before the loop starts, then start at the second iteration.